# Do radio waves go faster than the speed of light?

Tags: speed-of-light, faster-than-light

My science teacher used to say a lot of weird stuff, but I'm just making sure on this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. Radio waves ARE light, and so they travel at the speed of light.

Possible exception:

The speed of light $c$ that is always talked about as the "speed limit of the Universe" is the speed of light in vacuum. Light travels slower in a medium, and how much slower can be dependent on the wavelength of the light. So, in the right medium, radio waves could travel faster than optical waves, but I wouldn't call this "faster than light"; that would be very misleading...

Comment: Glad to help :) If you feel the answer is a satisfactory answer to your question, please accept it.

Comment: My science teacher said that her husband was a physics professor...sooooooooooooooooo...

Comment: In that case, your science teacher probably hasn't understood her husband's explanations. @Kyle 's explanation is right.

Answer (score 5):

No.

Radio waves are a form of electromagnetic radiation and so, *by definition* they travel at the speed of light (in a vacuum).

Have a look at the Wiki article on [EM radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EM_radiation), and more specifically, [Radio Waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EM_radiation#Radio_waves)